# Angular - how to highlight todays date in bsdaterangepicker

Tags: html, css, angular, angular-material

Code:

```
 <div class="col-lg-3 form-group">
 <label for="daterange"><strong> Date range</strong></label>
  <input type="text" name="daterange" autocomplete="off" bsDaterangepicker #datepickerMD="bsDaterangepicker"
  [bsConfig]="{ todayHighlight: true, rangeInputFormat : 'MM/DD/YYYY', dateInputFormat: 'MM/DD/YYYY', showWeekNumbers: false }"
  id="daterange" placeholder="Date Range" formControlName="daterangeapp" class="form-control"/>
   <div class="dr-input-group-append">
   <button class="calendar w-auto input-calendar-btn" (click)="datepickerMD.toggle()" type="button"
   [attr.aria-expanded]="datepickerMD.isOpen">
   <img tabindex="1" class="img-prop" src="assets/img/calendar_small.png" alt="Save"/>
   </button>
  </div>
 </div>
```

[image]

Am getting the daterange selection as above however, I need to highlight today's date in the picker as well. Tried `bsconfig` parameter todayHighlight: true it was not working.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this Github question](https://github.com/valor-software/ngx-bootstrap/issues/5229) and based on [this example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-amgo4f) you should be able to style Today's date based on the custom CSS class `.custom-today-class.`

So for example

```
.custom-today-class {
    background-color:red
}
```

You can see how it works in [this forked example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-amgo4f-jsfby3?file=styles.css).